# I am using pymodbus library, i can connect to the modbus devices that use modbus TCP/IP but the devices aren't responding with holding register values

Tags: modbus, pymodbus

I am using pymodbus. i have to establish connection and read some register values. I can connect but the devices aren't responding back to any query . I'm pretty sure register values are fine.I can ping the device so connectivity isn't the issue.

I tried reading different values for register, this is the error message: Error reading holding registers: Modbus error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error:[invalid Message] No response received, expected at least 8 bytes (0 received).

Comment: We cannot really help without more information (what is the device, full details of the request sent including slave ID etc). I would suggest that you start with a known good app (e.g. [mbpoll](https://github.com/epsilonrt/mbpoll)/[Modpoll](https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html)) and verify that you can read from the device using that before writing your own code.

Comment: I really appreciate you responding back unlike the Modbus devices. There are multiple PLC devices ( dent instruments).I was trying to read holding registers from starting address 4001.We have remote access to their network , we do not have much info. What I'm trying to do is Scan their network to identify devices and run through the complete range of valid Modbus slave ID’s and register addresses and option to add the specific device signature in the Database to identify the specific make/model of the Modbus device/controller.
I know it's a lot but i really need direction.

Comment: If you have the correct slave ID then you should get a response (e.g. `ILLEGAL DATA ADDRESS`). If there is no unit with the specified slave ID then there will be no response (and the issue you are seeing is to be expected). You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77235369/11810946) useful.